# 3D touch Ionic 3: How to open page

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I use 3D Touch Native Plugin in Ionic 3 app [3d-touch](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/3d-touch/).

How can I open page after application opened from 3D Touch Menu? 
In

> app.component.ts

my code:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  //3d Touch
  this.threeDeeTouch.isAvailable().then((isAvailable) => {
    if(isAvailable == true) {
      let actions: Array<ThreeDeeTouchQuickAction> = [
        {
          type: 'projects',
          title: 'Projects',
          iconType: 'Bookmark'
        },
        {
         type: 'messages',
          title: 'Messages',
          iconType: 'Message'
        },
      ];
      this.threeDeeTouch.configureQuickActions(actions);

      this.threeDeeTouch.onHomeIconPressed().subscribe((payload) => {

        alert(payload.type) ;

        //!!!!OPEN PAGE!!!!

      }) ;
    }
  });
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to navigate to tab pages or other pages not linked to tabs? Let me know so I can provide you with the correct answer. But to navigate to a normal page in your app you do the following:

***app.component.ts***

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

constructor(private threeDeeTouch: ThreeDeeTouch) {

//ThreeD Touch Configuration
    this.threeDeeTouch.isAvailable().then(isAvailable => console.log('3D Touch available? ' + isAvailable));

    this.threeDeeTouch.watchForceTouches()
      .subscribe(
        (data: ThreeDeeTouchForceTouch) => {
          console.log('Force touch %' + data.force);
          console.log('Force touch timestamp: ' + data.timestamp);
          console.log('Force touch x: ' + data.x);
          console.log('Force touch y: ' + data.y);
        }
      );

    let actions: Array<ThreeDeeTouchQuickAction> = [
      {
        type: 'projects',
        title: 'my projects',
        subtitle: 'check our projects!',
        iconType: 'bookmark'
      },
      {
        type: 'messages',
        title: 'Messages',
        subtitle: 'My Messages',
        iconType: 'message'
      }
    ];

    this.threeDeeTouch.configureQuickActions(actions);

    this.threeDeeTouch.onHomeIconPressed().subscribe(
     (payload) => {
       // returns an object that is the button you presed
       if (payload.type == 'projects') {
          this.nav.push(ProjectsPage);
       } else if (payload.type =='messages') {
          this.nav.setRoot(MessagesPage);

       console.log('Pressed the ${payload.title} button')
       console.log(payload.type)

     }
    )

    });
  }
```